# app.module gets errors on selectors declared in its child module, feature.module (angular 5)

Tags: angular

In Angular my `app.component.html` is simply this:

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

`App.module` looks like this:

```
import { ChildModule } from './child/child.module';
import { NgModule, Browser } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// Various other imports....
@NgModule({
   declarations:[AppComponent],
   imports:[BrowserModule,ChildModule],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The Child component looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, CommonModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppChild } from './appchild/appchild.component';
@NgModule({
   declarations:[AppChild],
   imports:[CommonModule]
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

And finally `appchild.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: // Angular's default path,
  styleUrls: // Default, auto created path again
})
export class AppChild implements OnInit {
constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The error I get when I render the page is

> Error: Template parse errors:
>
> 'app-child' is not a known element:

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the component in the exports array in its module this way:

```
import { NgModule, CommonModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppChild } from './appchild/appchild.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations:[AppChild],
  imports:[CommonModule],
  exports: [AppChild] // <-------- this line
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

This is because you want to access to that component by its selector, if you'd like to access to it by routes you wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Thanks. It thought that would've been it.